# Laravel 5.0 : Frontend after ajax login, session not read at view

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am doing ajax login on laravel front end website.
After ajax login I use the Auth::check() at my default.blade.php but it didn't work so, I just enter the variable in session and reload the page but it didn't work too on default page

Below is the code.

**Controller**

```
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
    $auth = false;
    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
//print_r($credentials); exit;
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        $auth = true; // Success
    }

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        if($auth == false){
            echo 'false';
        }else{
            echo 'true';
            $user = Auth::user();
            Session::put('frontuser', $user);
        }
        //$user = Auth::user();
        //print_r($user);
        //$value = Session::get('frontuser');
        //print_r($value);
    } exit;
  //  return redirect(URL::route('login_page'));
}
```

**default.blade.php**

```
<?php //$user = Auth::user();
        print_r(Session::get('frontuser')); echo 'ok'; ?>
        @if(Session::has('frontuser'))
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><div class="profile-btn">S</div></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Simon Rahme <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li><a href="my_account.html">My Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sell My Gift Card</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        @else

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#" class="login-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Log in</a></li> 
        </ul>
      @endif
```

Please help me, I am stuck.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all struggle, I just use the ajax for check the validation like the username and password match.

- If true, submit the login form
- Else show the error

One more thing if you do like my type you have to disable the token match for login route, otherwise it give token mismatch error after form submit

Thanks,